# How to show both stdout and stderr captures in pytest, but not logs capture?

Tags: python, testing, pytest

Originally, I need both blocks for pytest result

> Captured stdout call

and

> Captured stderr call

but not

> Captured log call

There is `--show-capture` option, but no `both` argument, unfortunately. Looks like that I must choose either one of the group, or all at the one time. Is there some way to acheive that?

```
pytest --show-capture=both

pytest: error: argument --show-capture: invalid choice:
'both' (choose from 'no', 'stdout', 'stderr', 'log', 'all')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the captured log sections at all, you can simply delete them from the report. Example: place the following code in a `conftest.py` in your root dir:

```
def pytest_runtest_logreport(report):
    report.sections[:] = [
        (title, content) for (title, content) in report.sections
        if not title == 'Captured log call'
    ]
```

and then use `--show-capture=all` as usual.